# Powershell to remove all Disabled-users from all DL's

Tags: powershell

I have the same question as this person:
[Remove all ex-employees from ALL distribution groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379922/remove-all-ex-employees-from-all-distribution-groups)

There are quite a few disabled users who left the company and need to be removed from all DLs.

Disabled users are locatedin: `uk.domain.int/USR/Disabled Users` 
DL's are located in: `uk.domain.int/USR/Distribution Lists`

There is the Powerscript provided by @Raymund
and I am not quite certain about the LDAP bit.

Would it be this in my case cos' I am not sure:

```
LDAP://OU=Disabled Users,OU=USR,DC=uk,DC=Domain,DC=int"
```

Just need to make sure that the PS script does not run on any other domain apart from the one uk.domain.int and targets disabled users only.

Please advise

ps: Powershell version: Major: 2 | Minor: 0 | Build -1 | Revision -1

Answer (score 0):

This LDAP Filter `LDAP://OU=Disabled Users,OU=USR,DC=uk,DC=Domain,DC=int"` will look into UK subdomain, USR OU , Disabled Users OU.

Although provided script commands will do the job I rather use `exchange management shell commands` + `active directory` powershell module commands for this purpose. This is just to give you some Ideas to write your own script via the right tools.

```
import-module activedirectory
$session = new-pssession -configurationname microsoft.exchange -connectionuri "http://yourcasserver.yourdomian.com/powershell/" -authentication kerberos -credential (get-credential)
import-pssession $session
$users = get-aduser -filter * -searchbase "OU=Disabled Users,OU=USR,DC=uk,DC=Domain,DC=int"
get-distributiongroup
```

Another advantage of using Powershell commands is you can make sure of effect of each command in script by running int against a test user and a test DistributionGroup.

It's wise to test your scripts in `lab environment` first. Specially when your dealing with exchange in an Enterprise.

Comment: trouble is, I don't have such an option to test in a lab environment :( - worried that the script will cause any bad effects after running...

Comment: It can be done on a compact lab, using evaluation licenses. 1 active directory domain controller and an exchange box. I also edited my post, Gave some directions on writing your own script using exchange and powershell  cmdlets.

Comment: thanks for the advise, yet I am not an advanced PowerShell user and would not dare to deploy the script as it might cause issues < then I am left with a P45 Note (you are fired)